# Get the number of images on a webpage

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet

Recreational languages win at code golf too much. This challenge is simple, when using higher level functions.

**The task is as follows:**

**Given any valid url, which is guaranteed to result in a valid HTML document** *(for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails, which has 9 images)*, count the number of images displayed from the resultant webpage.

Only images visible in the HTML code are counted, marked by the HTML `<img>` tag.

Websites that can continually load images (Google Images) are not valid tests.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75908/discussion-on-question-by-0liveradam8-get-the-number-of-images-on-a-webpage).

Comment: This is [tag:code-golf], right? The shortest code wins, right? Then why does a 61 byte answer beat an [10 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161698/48922)? If my answer is invalid in some way, just comment on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript, 61 bytes

As per [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/58974), the code needs to run under the same domain as the page being requested, to avoid CORS issues. Returns a Promise conatining the count.

```js
u=>fetch(u).then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>t.split`<img`.length-1)
```

Thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) for pointing out some code I forgot to update before posting, saving 3 bytes.

---

### Try it

```js
(f=
u=>fetch(`https://crossorigin.me/`+u).then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>t.split`<img`.length-1)
)(i.value=`https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161669/`).then(x=>o.innerText=x);b.addEventListener(`click`,_=>f(i.value).then(x=>o.innerText=x),0)
```

```html
<input id=i><button id=b>Count</button><pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: Why not `.match`? or `.split"<img"`?

Comment: `.match` works out longer in order to handle the case of their being no images. You're right on the second count, though; forgot to change it before posting. Thanks.

Comment: *there! Dunno how I did that!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 10 bytes

```
lg"<img"e=
```

Does not work online.

Description:

```
l          # read line
 g         # open url and get html
  "<img"   # this string
        e= # count arg2 in arg1
```

Comment: @downvoters what did I do wrong?

Comment: No idea. / Anyone who hates golfing languages is likely to know none of them. (otherwise they would know how hard it is to golf in those languages) Bash is not even a golfing language...

Comment: Can you add a TIO and/or an explanation? I don't know CJam and can't figure out how this is reading in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/) + [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) + [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/), 124 bytes

```
from selenium.webdriver import*
d=Firefox()
d.get(input())
c=len(d.find_elements_by_xpath('//img'))
d.quit()
print(c)
```

Notice that `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails` report 8 instead of 9. This is due to one of the `<img>` tag is contained by `<noscript>`, which is regarded as comment by a browser who enabled script.

<s>Changing `webdriver.Firefox` to `webdriver.Ie` may save 5 bytes... But I just dislike IE.</s>

**How to run:**

- First install Python 3, and Firefox
- install Selenium by `pip install selenium`
- Download gecko driver and put it to your path
- Run this script
- A Firefox will be started, ignore it and input the url to stdin
- The result will be shown on stdout

Comment: A manual count confirms that there are 9 `img` tags on that page.

Comment: @Shaggy One of them is in `<noscript>` tag which will not be rendered if browser support javascript; 3 of them are invisible to user. So there are 5 image _displayed_.

Comment: "*Only images **visible in the HTML code** are counted, marked by the HTML `<img>` tag.*"

Comment: Yes, and also "_count the number of images displayed from the resultant webpage_". I read this as "only **displayed** `<img>` tags are count.

Comment: You're right, there's a contradiction there. I suggest asking for clarification.

Comment: @tsh `@0liveradam8 So we just need to count <img> tags? – NoOneIsHere 19 hours ago   
@NoOneIsHere Yes! But you have to download the HTML code from a given URL first`

Comment: For some reason my laptop will not let me install silenium so can't test but can't you just do `import silenium as S` and then `S.webdriver.Firefox()` to save 7?

Comment: @Shaggy @NoOneIsHere Just updated to fit OP's comment (ignored `is_displayed` test).

Comment: @ElPedro it seems that `from selenium.webdriver import*` works, updated.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 + BeautifulSoup, 103 bytes

```
import bs4 as B
import urllib as U
print len(B.BeautifulSoup(U.urlopen(input()).read()).findAll('img'))
```

Can't do a TIO as `BeautifulSoup` is not available there. This reports 9 for  `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails`.

**Note:** A warning is displayed before the number as a parser is not specified and `lxml`is taken as the default. Adding the `lxml` parser explicitly suppresses the warning but costs another 7 bytes.

```
import bs4 as B
import urllib as U
print len(B.BeautifulSoup(U.urlopen(input()).read(),'lxml').findAll('img'))
```

Answer (score -1):

## Bash, grep, and wc, <s>45</s> 28 bytes

```bash
curl $1|grep -o "<img"|wc -l
```

*-17 bytes thanks to tsh*

Explanation:

```bash
curl $1                      # download html from first parametre
       |grep -o "<img"       # find all <img strings
                      |wc -l # count lines
```

Comment: What if there are multiple `<img>` tags on a line?

Comment: @downvoters what did I do wrong?

Comment: `grep -o '<img'` should works if you just want `<img` substring.

Comment: @nimi - if that's the case then the person who made the web site should be a code golfer and not a web developer :-)

Comment: @ElPedro No need of code golfer, just a minify tool should be enough.